# Is there a command to update Cargo to the latest official release?

Tags: rust, package-managers, rust-cargo

I seem to have diverging versions of `rustc` and `cargo` (I think),

```
$ rustc -V
rustc 1.9.0 (e4e8b6668 2016-05-18)
$ cargo -V
cargo 0.10.0-nightly (10ddd7d 2016-04-08)
```

Is there a command akin to

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

for upgrading `cargo`? I.e. something like

```
cargo install --upgrade cargo
```

Comment: `multirust update`. Or take a look at Rustup, but I don't yet have any experience with that.

Comment: `multirust` is deprecated, use https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rustup.rs

Answer (score 273, accepted):

You should update `rustc` and `cargo` based on how you installed it. If you used rustup, a `rustup update` should suffice. If you used a package manager or a binary installer, check those sources for an update.

`rustc` and `cargo` are shipped together, but that doesn't mean that their versions need to match. In fact, they *do not* match until Rust 1.26.0, when [the Cargo binary was changed to print the Rust version](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/commit/cc971ee517353e33428f33ccf329a6a42c2d7e33).

I have the same versions of `rustc` and `cargo` that you do; those are the ones that correspond to the Rust 1.9 release. There's nothing to worry about.

---

If you *really* want to, you can [download a nightly version of Cargo](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo#installing-cargo) or [compile your own](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo#compiling-from-source). As long as your version exists in your `PATH` before the older one, it will be used.

I used to do this with my local Rust builds in order to have a version of Cargo at all, although [rustup](http://rustup.rs/) now automatically uses the `cargo` from the most recent stable version when there isn't one available in the current toolchain, which is nice.

Comment: What if I inherited the system and have no idea how rust was installed but need to 'rustup update' it? I can run rustup update all day but it doesn't update the version of ~/.cargo/bin/rustc to the version rustup says was just installed.

Comment: Nevermind, I was in the folder of a project that happened to have a rust-toolchain file contained in it, overriding the default toolchain.

Answer (score 266):

tl;dr command `rustup update` will update both Rust and Cargo:

```
$ rustc --version
rustc 1.27.2 (58cc626de 2018-07-18)
$ cargo --version
cargo 1.27.0 (1e95190e5 2018-05-27)

$ rustup update stable
info: syncing channel updates for 'stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
info: latest update on 2018-08-02, rust version 1.28.0 (9634041f0 2018-07-30)
info: downloading component 'rustc'
info: downloading component 'rust-std'
info: downloading component 'cargo'
info: downloading component 'rust-docs'
info: removing component 'rustc'
info: removing component 'rust-std'
info: removing component 'cargo'
info: removing component 'rust-docs'
info: installing component 'rustc'
info: installing component 'rust-std'
info: installing component 'cargo'
info: installing component 'rust-docs'

$ rustc --version
rustc 1.28.0 (9634041f0 2018-07-30)
$ cargo --version
cargo 1.28.0 (96a2c7d16 2018-07-13)
```

Answer (score 31):

You also need to change the default:

```
> rustc --version
rustc 1.41.0 (5e1a79984 2020-01-27)

> rustup update stable

> rustc --version
rustc 1.41.0 (5e1a79984 2020-01-27)

> rustup default stable-x86_64-apple-darwin

> rustc --version
rustc 1.47.0 (18bf6b4f0 2020-10-07)
```

Comment: For those who are Rust newbies like me, this was it - changing the default, as just update wasn't enough.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be required any longer.

Answer (score 13):

Use cargo to update itself:

```
cargo install cargo --force
```

This recompiles the package and installs the latest version.

I decided to post this after seeing that rustup didn't update cargo to 1.57

Comment: While this might work sometimes, in general this is not supposed to work, and you are not supposed to be able to install a different version of Cargo via Cargo itself: https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/11266#issuecomment-1286032635

Answer (score 4):

You can edit the version of cargo and rust you're using by using the rustup cli. You can give it a specific version or specify a channel like nightly or beta.

For example:

```
rustup override set nightly
```

..and then run `rustup update`.

Comment: This does not answer the question.